# Displaying a UITableView Inside the MKPinAnnotationView

Tags: ios, ios5, mkmapview

I am trying to display a UITableView inside the callout of the MKPinAnnotationView. I added the UITableViewController inside my storyboard file. I am using the following code to assign the leftAccessoryView to the UITableView.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil; 

    NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"ZillowPropertyDetailsIdentifier"; 

    MKPinAnnotationView *propertyDetailsView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [mv 
                                                            dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

    if (!propertyDetailsView) 
    {
        propertyDetailsView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                    initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                    reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

        // get view from storyboard 
        PropertyDetailsViewController *propertyDetailsViewController = (PropertyDetailsViewController *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PropertyDetailsIdentifier"];

        propertyDetailsView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = propertyDetailsViewController.view;

        [propertyDetailsView setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen];
        propertyDetailsView.animatesDrop = YES; 
        propertyDetailsView.canShowCallout = YES; 

    }
    else 
    {
        propertyDetailsView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return propertyDetailsView; 
}
```

PropertyDetailsViewController:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

When I click on the pin it crashes with BAD_EXCEPTION or something.

Comment: Is your propertyDetailsViewController valid (non-nil), with a valid view?

Comment: properyDetailsViewController is valid and it is in the Storyboard. I updated the code with PropertyDetailsViewController. Few methods that might be the point of interest.

Comment: Let me try to use the UIPopUPController and display the tableview inside that.

Comment: Is it possible that you are not instantiating the UITableView anywhere?

Comment: Actually I believe that you cannot display a UITableView inside a callout. I need to turn the callout off and then display a popup and then inside popup display the uitableview.

Comment: Totally forgot that UIPopOverController is only for iPad. Back to square one!

Comment: I thought about it and it turns out that it is NOT a good idea to show a UITableView for an iPhone app. For iPad it does makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You only have a memory problem. When you do

```
PropertyDetailsViewController *propertyDetailsViewController = (PropertyDetailsViewController *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PropertyDetailsIdentifier"];
```

That returns an **autoreleased** PropertyDetailsViewController. Later on you just asign it's view to the callout accessory view but noone is retaining the view controller. Son when the method finishes, the viewcontrollers retain count is zero and it's deallocated. When anything on that view controller is accessed, a BAD_EXCEPTION is raised.

Actually, BAD_EXCEPTION is usually a memory problem (too many releases, two autoreleases, etc.) They can be traced better activating the 'enable zombie objects' flag. This makes the objects to not be deallocated fully so you can see which one fails.